# merge two files based on common column values

Tags: python, bash, awk, merge

I have file1 likes:

```
1 A aa
2 A bb
3 A cc
4 A dd
5 B xx
6 C yy
7 C zz
```

And a file2:

```
1 A 11
2 B 22
3 C 33
```

And I would like to merge file1 and file 2 into a file3 based on the 2nd column, such that:

```
1 A aa 11
2 A bb 11
3 A cc 11
4 A dd 11
5 B xx 22
6 C yy 33
7 C zz 33
```

Which way is the simplest? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) will save you a lot of time if you use Python. So if your DataFrames are `df1`:

```
   1   2
0
1  A  aa
2  A  bb
3  A  cc
4  A  dd
5  B  xx
6  C  yy
7  C  zz
```

and `df2`:

```
   1   2
0
1  A  11
2  B  22
3  C  33
```

then you can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=1, right_on=1)
```

to get

```
   1 2_x  2_y
0  A  aa   11
1  A  bb   11
2  A  cc   11
3  A  dd   11
4  B  xx   22
5  C  yy   33
6  C  zz   33
```

Comment: Thank you. I originally used pandas, but my files are too big to load. Even for the small files, I got an error saying: "You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. Try concat instead". I don't know why the data type of the two files become different when I "pd.read_csv('file.txt')".

Comment: @SteveXu That indicates that you are merging on an int64 column and a generic object column. You can convert the columns with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html). How big are the files?

Comment: Many files are about 1G. Loading them first into pandas is a pain.

Comment: I tried different methods and finally go back to pandas. I tried to reduce my files first before I join them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Which way is the **simplest**

I am not sure what do you mean by **simplest**. For this problem, 
you can simply use `join`:

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.3 file1 file2
```

For the given example, the above command generates the desired output. If your file is not sorted, you can also add `--nocheck-order` option.